# is my ExecutorService Implementation Correct?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable-statement

I am new to `Multithreading` and I am trying make my program faster using `ExecutorService`. Below is y implementation but, my program is still not working fast. Can you please look at my code and advise?

It basically reads the list of email addresses and stores in the `ArrayList`. I use the `ExecutorService` and loop through the `ArrayList` and call a Callable class does some processing and returns a Boolean.

```
ArrayList<String> emailAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);
for (int i = 0; i < emailAddressList.size(); i++) {
    Future<Boolean> resultFromThread =  executor.submit(new Verify(emailAddressList.get(i)));
    bufferedWriter.write(emailAddressList.get(i) + "|" + resultFromThread.get());
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
}

executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

===========================================================================

```
public class Verify implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private String email;


    public Verify(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        Boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = Validator2.isAddressValid(email);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why have you chosen 7 threads?

Answer (score 2):

In each iteration of the loop, two actions are performed:

1. A Callable is scheduled to run with the Executor
2. Immediately after that - yet before another task is scheduled - the code waits for the Executor to complete the Callable just submitted.

That way, all Callables are still executed in a serial fashion (we wait to complete one before we submit another), rather than executing them in parallel.

A simple solution might be to submit all callables for execution first. Then, in a separate loop, the wait for them to complete and to process the results. That way, the performance shall improve because of parallel processing of the Callables.

Example:

```
List<Future<Boolean>> futures ... ;
for (int i = 0; i < emailAddressList.size(); i++) {
    futures.add(executor.submit(new Verify(emailAddressList.get(i))));
} 

for (int i = 0; i < emailAddressList.size(); i++)
    bufferedWriter.write(emailAddressList.get(i) + "|" + futures.get(i).get());
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
}
```

Note that this code waits for the Callables to complete in the order they were submitted to the Executor. This may not necesarily be the case. If the order of the adresses in the resulting writer is not important, one may consider a completely asychronous processing. In Java 8, this can be achieved e.g using the [CompleteableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

You have effectively made your code synchronous and single-threaded without offering any advantage to using a threaded executor. When calling resultFromThread.get(), it will block the main thread and will prevent the next loop iteration that submits the next Task to execute from running until the previous one completes. If you want the submitted Verify tasks to run concurrently, you should submit all of the tasks first in one loop appended to a `List<Future<Boolean>>`. Then, in another loop, you can iterate through each of those and then call .get(), such that the main thread will await completion of all executions, but won't stop the 7 other threads from executing concurrently.

Comment: Thanks man. I got it. So I want to still write the progress while the code is executing, I would have to the write operation from the parellel thread itself? Correct?

Comment: david a's answer is exactly what I am describing in words.